# Working with signature fields using Prawn and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, prawn, prawnto

[image: Signature fields in two columns]I'm trying to draw a set of signature fields at the bottom of page with terms and conditions. I'm brand new to Prawn so I'm having a little trouble with this. I looked at the `column_box` method and there looks like there is some `left_side` and `right_side` methods in some of the documentation but those methods don't seem to be working (I get a `NoMethodError`) or something.

What I want is two signature fields with text underneath each. One of the left side of the page and one on the right side. How do I do this?

My code sample:

```
column_box([0, cursor], :columns => 2, :width => bounds.width) do
    text "_______________________"
    text "Signature 1"
    right_side
    text "_______________________"
    text "Signature 2"
end
```

And the error I'm getting:

```
undefined local variable or method `right_side' for #<Prawnto::TemplateHandlers::Renderer:0x00000005b3a420>
```

Comment: Can you show us what you tried and what it looks like... and an example of what you'd like it to look like instead?

Comment: Oops! I meant to actually do that before posting.

Comment: Don't forget to add the relevant snippet of code... also a full stacktrace of the error would be good (and pointing out to us which line of code is the one listed as throwing the error) :)

Comment: Ok well since I'm trying to do this from scratch, all I need is a code sample or an example of how to do this. Its not really that I have a stack trace error (but I'll post the one I get when I try to use the `right_side` method.

I just feel like this should be pretty straight forward what I'm trying to do.

Comment: According to the docs, `right_side` is a method *of* a column box... ie you probably need to call it on an actual instance of a column box, not sure it'd work if called just inside the scope of the block passed to the column_box (but could be wrong). Also it just returns the X-coordinate of the right-hand side of the column... I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: Looking at what column_box does... it only flows to the right if the content goes below the end of the bounding-area... you probably want to be explicit that that stuff sits on the right (instead of just hoping it'll flow that way). Have you tried creating a second column-box for the stuff that goes on the right?

Comment: Note: I'm not a prawn expert and am mainly just guessing) :D

Comment: Oh well I'm hoping someone with prawn experience can help me out here :) A second column box shouldn't be necessary right since I can pass in how many columns should be in the column box. Wish this was more like html. I know how do this with divs! haha

Comment: yeah, but that's just relying on a right-hand column happening by accident because it happens to overflow the column-box... not doing it on purpose by choosing two columns you want to see, and putting the right-hand stuff in the right-hand column :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make your column_box having 2 columns, then adjust height matching the size of underlines and the text below it, so it would break columns between them.
It would be something like:

```
Prawn::Document.generate("hello.pdf") do
    column_box([0, cursor],:columns => 2, :width => bounds.width, :height => 75) do
        # For default font 2x 25px lines are enough to break an 75px height column
        # You should adjust height of the box and font_size to match
        # your desired 2-column effect
        font_size 25
        text("___________")
        text("Foo")
        text("___________")
        text("Bar")
    end
end
```

This outputs:[image: Foo Bar divided in two columns]

Don't forget you have to specify `:columns => 2` and `height` attributes of `column_box` for desired 2-column effect.

Comment: This works great! I just needed to tweak my current code with the height parameter so get it to behave. That was my issue, thanks!